# Smart unlock says "no devices" despite one being connected

Tags: 7.0-nougat, smart-lock, huawei-honor-6

Honor 6A, Android 7.0. Bluetooth active, smartwatch paired and connected, phone contacts and calls are visible from the smartwatch, smartwatch accepts files via Bluetooth. However, when I try to set up smart unlock, it says "no devices" and the phone keeps asking for PIN every time I unlock it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try impairing, clearing Bluetooth app cache, pairing again

Comment: @beeshyams Cleared cache for all apps. No effect.